# Django 2.0 haystack whoosh update index, rebuild index throw error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-haystack, whoosh, django-2.0

I am using django 2.0 with haystack+whoosh as a search. I configured as it is said in the documentation. Occurred problem is when i run `./manage.py rebuild_index` it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 36, in handle
    call_command('clear_index', **options)
  File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 133, in call_command
    ', '.join(sorted(valid_options)),
TypeError: Unknown option(s) for clear_index command: batchsize, workers. Valid options are: commit, help, interactive, no_color, nocommit, noinput, pythonpath, settings, skip_checks, stderr, stdout, traceback, using, verbosity, version.
```

after that i tried `update_index` it shows me this error:

```
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 214, in handle self.update_backend(label, using)
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 257, in update_backend
commit=self.commit, max_retries=self.max_retries)
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 84, in do_update
backend.update(index, current_qs, commit=commit)
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py", line 185, in update
doc = index.full_prepare(obj)
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 208, in full_prepare
self.prepared_data = self.prepare(obj)
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 199, in prepare
self.prepared_data[field.index_fieldname] = field.prepare(obj)
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 205, in prepare
return self.convert(super(CharField, self).prepare(obj))
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 88, in prepare
values = self.resolve_attributes_lookup(current_objects, attrs)
File "/home/zorig/.virtualenvs/ftm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 131, in resolve_attributes_lookup
values.append(current_object())
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'
```

So has anyone faced this error? Is it related to django 2.0 because i managed it work well with django 1.11.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Maybe someone will answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684419/is-django-haystack-2-6-1-compatible-with-django-2-0

Answer (score 2):

Your installed version of Haystack does not support Django 2.0. Support for Django 2.0 was added in [Haystack 2.8](https://pypi.org/project/django-haystack/2.8.0/), which was released in March 2018.