# Is Django-haystack 2.6.1 compatible with Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-haystack, django-2.0

My question is simple (as per title). Is the current Django-haystack compatible with the newest Django 2.0? Is anyone using this combination?

The requirements in the docs and at PYPI suggest that it is:

- https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/#requirements
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-haystack/2.6.1

But the following user faces issues as well as I do when trying to use it with Django 2.0:

- [Django 2.0 haystack whoosh update index, rebuild index throw error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476501/django-2-0-haystack-whoosh-update-index-rebuild-index-throw-error)

The same setup works with Django 1.11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haystack 2.6.1 does not support Django 2.0. The [README](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/b54d3ee6504997c2649f3fc03a97b8fc023c46e7/README.rst) said *a supported version of Django* but did not explicitly specify the supported versions. If you look at the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/b54d3ee6504997c2649f3fc03a97b8fc023c46e7/setup.py#L15), `install_requires` contained `'Django>=1.8,<1.12'.`

[Support for Django 2.0](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1582) was added in Haystack 2.8, which was released in March 2018.